# Open curly brace doesn't detect it's closing brace & catch another brace in PHP

Tags: php, curly-braces

I usually do web development in visual studio code.
Sometimes I'm getting a problem with curly braces.
My code is like this:

```
if() {} else {***(open_brace1)***

  //some code here
  if() {} else {***(open_brace2)***
    //some code here
  }***(closing_brace2)***

}***(closing_brace1)***
```

The ***open_brace1*** catches the ***closing_brace2*** and closing_brace1 hasn't an open brace.
What I can do about this?

Comment: Post a *minimal* reproduction case with *actual code* that exhibits the problem claimed. It is also unclear what “catching” means — a highlighting or navigation issue in Visual Studio Code, or something else? (If it’s an issue in the UI, also consider include a screen capture.)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Actually, the issue with the UI. When we click on an open brace usually the IDE shows a line which is ending up with the closing brace of that open brace. But here, the line end with another closing brace, but not the closing brace of the open brace. That is my problem